# PowerShellへコピペする際、×だけコピぺ出来ないのは何故ですか？

Tags: windows, powershell

PowerShellへコピペすると、×だけコピぺ出来ないのですが何故ですか？

---

**コピペ元**
テキストエディタ

```
Set-Location -Path L:\1\地×図\
```

**コピペ先**
PowerShell

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-Location -Path L:\1\地図\
```

Comment: これと同じ問題でしょうか？→[PowerShellで中点"・"が入らない](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/b096ae4b-f639-4883-9369-383311e4081e/powershell123912001328857quot12539quot1236420837124251239412356?forum=powershellja)

Answer (score 0):

直接の回答にはなりませんが、ターミナルエミュレータの [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) を使用して PowerShell を起動した場合には、問題なく貼り付けができました。

(私は試していませんが) 他にも [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) 辺りを使用しても結果が変わるかもしれません。